# Can't return the value on snapshot on firebase cloud storage

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I would like to return the value retrieved by snapshot with return. However, if I return it here, it is undefined.

How can I get the downloadURL inside out?

```js
const downloadURL = await storage
  .ref()
  .child(`${directory}/` + id)
  .put(file, metadata)
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL)
      // successfully file info

      return downloadURL
    })
  })
console.log('download', downloadURL)
// get undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have missed a `return` statement:

```
const downloadURL = await storage
  .ref()
  .child(`${directory}/` + id)
  .put(file, metadata)
  .then((snapshot) => {
    // ⬇⬇ return was missing here
    return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
      .then((downloadURL) => {
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL)
        // successfully file info

        return downloadURL
      })
  })
console.log('download', downloadURL)
```

However, avoid using both [`async-await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [promise chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining) simultaneously.

If your function `async`, you can rewrite it as:

```
const snapshot = await storage.ref()
  .child(`${directory}/` + id)
  .put(file, metadata)
const downloadURL = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
console.log('download', downloadURL)
```

Comment: Note that the [`getDownloadURL()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getdownloadurl) method is asynchronous: you need to use `await` in the first proposed solution. Answer has been adapted.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec It seems we both wrote the same change at once.